# Viewport view to Camera view

Tags: 3d-view, camera

There are many related topics in this fora, but I could not find a question/answer to my specific problem. Sorry upfront if I missed an answer to this.

I think the perspective given by the 3D Viewport is the best, it's much less distorted than the one offered by the Camera view. I am struggling to find a solution to render my image with the same perspective as in the 3D Viewport. This may be by design for various good reasons. Not debating that, just trying to find my way here.

**What I'm looking for is this in my final render,** a more relaxed perspective (this is the 3D Viewport view):
[image]

**What I would like to avoid is this,** a distorted view in my final render (this is the Camera view):
[image]

If anyone has an idea on how to achieve this it would be very helpful and thank you for your time.

UPDATE: Here's a render of my project, focal length 80mm in both viewport and camera:[image]

Comment: Hi :). Simply match the camera's focal length to your viewport camera. They work the same.

Comment: @JachymMichal - that worked very well, thank you! In addition I also repositioned the camera by using the Camera to view option (and checking it off when finished).

Comment: I'm glad you made it work, good luck with your project :)

Comment: Thanks @JachymMichal I posted an image from the project :)

Comment: Very nice! Love the sense of scale in that scene. Can i check more of your work somewhere? Insta? Behance? :)

Comment: @JachymMichal - sure I have a portfolio over at Artstation: https://www.artstation.com/tegnemaskin and also on Insta: https://www.instagram.com/tegnemaskin/ . I have one on Behance as well but it is the same as on Artstation more or less.